# fastet way to read bytes from port and write them to the file

Tags: vb.net, file

Im trying to read 1536 bytes in a cycle from the com port and append them to the bin file. It seems too slow. 10sec = 100kb written to the file. I'm using USB FS, so the problem is not on usb's speed. 
How i call the sub:

```
    If receivedData.Contains("mcu_r") Then
            Call Read(spObj, 1536)
            receivedData = vbNullString


            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Read and save to the file sub:

```
 Public Function Read(ByVal port As SerialPort, ByVal count As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim buffer(count - 1) As Byte
        Dim readBytes As Integer
        Dim totalReadBytes As Integer
        Dim offset As Integer
        Dim remaining As Integer = count

        Try
            Do
                readBytes = port.Read(buffer, offset, remaining)
                offset += readBytes
                remaining -= readBytes
                totalReadBytes += readBytes
            Loop While remaining > 0 AndAlso readBytes > 0
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            ReDim Preserve buffer(totalReadBytes - 1)
        End Try
        Using vFs As New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\myfile.bin", FileMode.Append) 'save
            vFs.Write(buffer, 0, 1536)
        End Using
        'lable_count = lable_count + 2048
        'Dim strTemp As New StringBuilder(512 * 2)
        'For Each b As Byte In buffer
        '    strTemp.Append(Conversion.Hex(b))
        'Next

        'Dim builder As New StringBuilder(strTemp.ToString)
        'Dim startIndex = builder.Length - (builder.Length Mod 2)

        'For i As Int32 = startIndex To 2 Step -2
        '    builder.Insert(i, " "c)
        'Next i
        'Form1.RichTextBox1.Text &= builder.ToString()
        'Form1.RichTextBox1.Text &= strTemp.ToString
        Dim BytesToSend(0) As Byte
        Dim OutBuffer
        BytesToSend(0) = &H11             ' call Dump eeprom (44)
        'dummy
        Dim v As String
        OutBuffer = BytesToSend

        ' Bytes are outputted in the order of their Index Number(Index)!

        Form1.spObj.Write(OutBuffer, 0, OutBuffer.length)
        Return buffer

    End Function
```

Comment: Serial ports can only go as fast as their Baudrate allows.  100KB in 10 sec is about  equal to 110,000 baud, a standard as-fast-as-you-can rate.  You'd have to look at the other end of the USB cable to see if the device can go higher, probably not.

Comment: You should use the DataReceived event and buffer the data in chunks of your required size.  Here is a link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @HansPassant my port parameters max value 128000 baud rate. What is the max baud rate value for visual studio?

Comment: @dbasnett i always thoght that receiveevent handler is slow

Comment: Only 110,000 is a standard baudrate.  Devices *may* support alternatives, and the USB driver may even support those as well, but it is not very common. Nothing to do with VS, it is the driver and device that determine what is possible.  If the documented maximum is 128,000 then that's the eleven the dial can go to.

Comment: @James_BK - without it you have to have some mechanism for knowing when you have bytes.  Compared to that it is not.